# Add a tooltip to a CStatic Ctrl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tooltip

Is it possible to add a tooltip to a `CStatic` control in Visual C++6? How?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a [CToolTipCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b4cb3a5%28VS.80%29.aspx) in order to add tooltips to any part of your window, dialog or control.